Extract the last few seconds of a GoPro video losslessly while keeping the telemetry info and the original stream order
I'm looking for a program that can extract the last few seconds of a GoPro video losslessly while keeping the telemetry info and the original stream order.

OS: Windows, Linux, iOS, iPadOS, or Android.
Price/license: Any.

FFmpeg is incapable of doing so unless maybe if one recompiles it with some patch, which I'm unwilling to blow my time into at the moment.
